# "No persistent classes found for query class" error when I try map object using HQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hql

I would like to map custom object directly from database (`ApplicationStatus` to `Status`) using HQL constructor method. But result of query is empty and Hibernate return message like below.

```
2020-08-14 17:22:45.224  WARN 6668 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.hibernate.hql.internal.QuerySplitter   : HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: select new com.tt.practices6.map.Status(stat.id, stat.status, stat.application.name, stat.application.production.name, stat.log, stat.requestTime, stat.checked, stat.idUserChecked) from com.tt.practices6.model.ApplicationStatus stat
```

Here is my hibernate config xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "https://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">passwd</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</property>

        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="com.tt.practices6.model.ApplicationStatus"/>
        <mapping class="com.tt.practices6.model.Application"/>
        <mapping class="com.tt.practices6.model.Production"/>
        <mapping class="com.tt.practices6.map.Status"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Method with query:

```
    @Transactional
    @GetMapping("/applicationsStatus/map/list")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Status>> getAllMappedApplicationsStatus() {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Query<Status> statusesQuery = session.createQuery(
                "select new com.tt.practices6.map.Status(stat.id, stat.status, " +
                        "stat.application.name, stat.application.production.name, " +
                        "stat.log, stat.requestTime, stat.checked, stat.idUserChecked) " +
                        "from com.tt.practices6.model.ApplicationStatus stat"
        );

        System.out.println(statusesQuery.getResultList());
        List<Status> statuses = new ArrayList<>(statusesQuery.list());

        tx.rollback();
        sessionFactory.close();

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(statuses);
    }
```

ApplicationStatus entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "applications_status")
public class ApplicationStatus {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private boolean status;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="guid_application", referencedColumnName = "guid")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Application application;

    private String log;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime requestTime;

    private boolean checked;

    @Column(name = "id_user_checked")
    private Long idUserChecked;

    public ApplicationStatus() {
    }

   // setters and getters
```

Status object:

```
public class Status {

    private Long id;

    private boolean status;

    private String applicationName;

    private String productionName;

    private String log;

    private LocalDateTime requestTime;

    private boolean checked;

    private Long idUserChecked;

    public Status(Long id, boolean status, String applicationName, String productionName, String log, LocalDateTime requestTime, boolean checked, Long idUserChecked) {
        this.id = id;
        this.status = status;
        this.applicationName = applicationName;
        this.productionName = productionName;
        this.log = log;
        this.requestTime = requestTime;
        this.checked = checked;
        this.idUserChecked = idUserChecked;
    }

// setters and getters
```

Answer (score 0):

Check table name at @Table annotation, maybe all caps would work . Probably you need to provide schema too.

Comment: Caps didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

**Status** class is not declared with any @Entity annotation. But defined a mapping for it `<mapping class="com.tt.practices6.map.Status"/>`.
So, Hibernate will expect an Entity **Status**.

For your purpose, you can first query the ApplicationStatus. Then after fetching the values into `Query<ApplicationQuery>`, you can create a custom object. Or else, remove the mapping in xml & try your code.

Comment: I deleted `Status` from XML and problem is the same. Also I try with simple query `Query<ApplicationStatus> q = session.createQuery("select stat from com.tt.practices6.model.ApplicationStatus stat");` and still problem is the same...

Comment: firstly, Why are your taking a full qualified name in query for `com.tt.practices6.model.ApplicationStatus`. use just `ApplicationStatus`. Secondly, when you are projecting a complete class, `SELECT stat` is optional. For Example, `String hql = "FROM Employee E WHERE E.id = 10"`;
`Query query = session.createQuery(hql);`

Comment: With `ApplicationStatus` only, hibernate return error `ApplicationStatus is not mapped`. Also query without `SELECT` has problem with `No persistent classes found for query class`. Do you know any other solution to map custom object directly from database? I'm giving up with HQL...